# REST api best practice

Tags: rest, api, jersey

I create rest api and I have a POST which has many comments. What is the better url to get post comments

```
//Get all comments of a post
GET /posts/{postId}/comments
or
GET /comments/{postId}

//Create new comment
POST /posts/{postId}/comments
or 
POST /comments/{postId}
```

A POST has many CATERORY and a CATEGORY can belong to many POST
How I can create a post with ,for example, 3 categories. And how I can connect a specific existing post to a specific existing category

Answer (score 1):

> What is the better url to get post comments

REST doesn't care about your spelling conventions for URI -- that's part of the point.  So you should use whatever spellings are consistent with your local conventions.

Depending on your API and representations, it *may* be useful to think about [relative references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) in your hierarchy.  For instance, if your base URI is `/posts/{postId}/abstract`, then the relative reference `../comments` can be resolved to `/posts/{postId}/comments`; but there is no analogous trick to get you from `/abstracts/{postId}` to `/comments/{postId}`.

> - How I can create a post with ,for example, 3 categories
> - how I can connect a specific existing post to a specific existing category

How would you do it with a web site?  Having done that, how would you make the web site machine readable?